# Hide items of autocomplete with watch Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, watch, angularjs-watch

I'm trying to make an autocomplete with $scope.watch, and it work perfect but when I choose an option, doing click in the item, it put on the input but the items don't hide because when I put it in the input the watch be activated again...

I don'y know how to hide the items when I choose one of its.

Any help..

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" />
<ul class="listFavoInbox">
    <li ng-repeat="favo in resultAuto" ng-click="itemFavoInbox(favo.first,favo.id)">
        {{favo.first}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

```
$scope.selected = "";
$scope.arrayFavo = [
    {'id': 1, 'first': 'John', 'last': 'Depp', 'age':52, 'gender':'male'}, 
    {'id': 2, 'first': 'Sally', 'last': 'JoHanson', 'age':13, 'gender':'female'},
    {'id': 3, 'first': 'Taylor', 'last': 'Swift', 'age':22, 'gender':'female'},
];

$scope.$watch('selected', function() {
    $scope.resultAuto = [];
    for(var i=0; i<$scope.arrayFavo.length; i++){

        var text = angular.lowercase($scope.arrayFavo[i].first);
        var search = angular.lowercase($scope.selected);

        // console.log("text array",text);
        // console.log("text",$scope.selected);

        if ( search != "" ){
            if ( text.indexOf(search) !== -1 ){
                $scope.resultAuto.push($scope.arrayFavo[i]);
            }

            console.log($scope.resultAuto);
        }
    }
});

$scope.itemFavoInbox = function (name,id){
    $scope.selected = name;
    $scope.resultAuto = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `$watch()` for this. Use [`filter`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

```
<input type="text" ng-model="selected" />
<ul class="listFavoInbox">
    <li ng-repeat="favo in arrayFavo | filter:selected" ng-click="itemFavoInbox(favo.first,favo.id)">
        {{favo.first}}
    </li>
</ul>
```

Or `filter:{first: selected}` for selected field;

[Fiddle;](http://jsfiddle.net/f771cL4j/)

Comment: ok, it is good , but my real questions is, when I choose a items , I need hide the items list , this is my problem.

Answer (score -1):

you can use ng-hide =true;
when click on itemFavoInbox();
and false when watcher will acti